# How to remove oil based polyurethane painted over water based paint

Tags: painting, polyurethane

I used oil based polyurethane to paint over trim painted with water based white paint with satin gloss.  It has left a yellow hue. It's been about a week since poly was applied, so it has not fully cured.  I wanted a more glossy finish and realize I should have used water based poly. What is the easiest way to remove the oil based polyurethane?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a way to remove large areas of poly that don't involve either equally large amounts of solvents (needing ventilation and an organic-vapor mask) or abrasives (which risks sanding through your paint).

Comment: Glossy and clear are different things; which one do you want (or do you want both?) In general oil-based poly is always going to add some color; water-based may be clear. Gloss (reflectiveness) is more a matter of what additives the finish carries (you can get higher or lower gloss in both oil and water based) and how well you've applied it. If you just want it glossier, you _should_ be able to add a thin high-gloss topcoat of high-gloss oil-based poly, but that won't do anything about the color shift.